# How to create custom CSS classes using Material UI v5 theme?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI v5 in my application along with `react-d3-tree` which renders SVG tree charts. It offers an API to include custom CSS class names in the `<path>` elements linking the tree nodes to one another. I would like to pass custom class names to `react-d3-tree` and be able to use MUI's theme variables. Thus simply importing a `.css` file will not be enough.

How can I create statically named custom CSS classes using MUI v5 and take advantage of the MUI theme definition that styles other parts of my app?

Comment: It would help if your question included a simple example of code showing how you want to use the CSS class along with a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) with that code.

Comment: I want a CSS class name string from MUI to pass to an SVG element's props. Frankly I cannot see how a code example could make this any clearer...

Comment: A code example (particularly a working example via code sandbox or similar) makes it easier and quicker for someone to provide a clear answer that includes a working example. The 3 upvotes on my comment so far are probably from people who would have answered your question if you had already added such an example.

Comment: The MUI docs mention `tss-react` (a third party package) that gives you access to a function similar to the old `makeStyles` but using Emotion instead of JSS. You could use this to create class names to pass through. Another option is to bake your own similar code making use of Emotions `css` function.

Answer (score 1):

There is the https://mui.com/api/global-styles/ component.

Usage:

```
return (
  <>
    <GlobalStyles
      styles={(theme) => ({
        h1: { color: theme.palette.primary.main },
        h2: { color: "green" },
        ".some-class": { backgroundColor: "lightpink" }
      })}
    />
    <h1>This is a h1 element</h1>
    <h2>This is a h2 element</h2>
    <button className="some-class">Pink</button>
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to locally define a class and reuse it is to define the css class at a `sx` property of a parent component, like in the following example:

```
function Child({ message, className }) {
  return <Typography className={className}>{message}</Typography>;
}

function Parent() {
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        '.childClass': {
          color: 'primary.main'
        }
      }}
    >
      <Child message="Child with no css class defined" />

      <Child className="childClass" message="Child with css class defined" />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

In this example, `'primary.main'` resolves to `theme.pallete.primary.main`, as mentioned [here](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#palette).

Comment: I love you for this comment <3